# Title vs honorific

Tags: honorifics

The [Wikipedia article on honorifics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorific#Modern_English_honorifics) states that

> Some honorifics act as complete replacements for a name, as "Sir" or "Ma'am", or "Your Honor"

I had initially thought that titles generally needed a name appended onto the end (`Mr Smith`, `Mrs Jones`, `Dr Williams`) and that honorific was used for a term of address (e.g. `Ma'am`, `Sir` (when used to address a teacher, not when used to specify a male who has been knighted!)), but it seems I was obviously wrong!

Is there a word to specifically denote those words / terms which I *thought* were honorifics (i.e. `Ma'am`, `Sir`, `Your Honour`)?

Comment: In the introduction to that article, you will see the link to *[style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_(manner_of_address))*, wherein it is noted that *honorific* is an alternative term, both referring to an official or legally recognized *[title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title)*. Perhaps the article at *Honorific* needs to be moved to *Honorific title*.

Comment: T. C. Harris seems at least largely correct.

This is an old Question, in no way helped by Wikipedians allowing that author to get away with defining those terms as “honorific” as though that were a noun. It’s not and they aren’t and there ain’t no such critter.

“An honorific style of address” would be one thing, the “style of address” being what mattered. “An honorific” is an adjective without a noun.

On titles and formal styles of address read, eg, *Debrett’s Correct Form* or *Burke’s Peerage* or just an office version of *Webster’s Dictionary*… and please note their length!

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin _Honorific_ is absolutely a noun as well as an adjective.

Comment: Janus, if that's so why can you not present three or four examples, with supporting explanations from sources such as Burkes' or DeBrett's or Webster's?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/618775/2085).

Answer (score 1):

The question asks: Is there a word specifically to denote those words/terms which had been thought to be honorifics (i.e. Ma'am, Sir, Your Honour)?

Yes, there is a word specifically to denote those words/terms, and that word is none other than: Honorific