# What kind of word is "Brother" or "Sister"?

Tags: terminology, titles, kinship-terms, honorifics, vocatives

Some Christians use "Brother" or "Sister" before referring to someone, and usually they prefix the word before their name (e.g. Brother Aaron).

I am asking what the use of this word is called. Would it be considered an honorific or title? If so, what type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capitalization of "sister" and "brother"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172615/capitalization-of-sister-and-brother) 'Sister and Brother are capitalized in the same way as Doctor -- when used as honorifics or titles.' [Ben Voight] See [Britannica sense 4](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/brother).